# Arithmetic of composite counter

Tags: numbering, counters, calculations

How do I calculate and display an incremented value of a numeric composite counter, such as `\thesubsection`? Do I try  to extract and increment the "decimal" part separately and then glue the result back together?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
    Next section would be: \the\numexpr\thesection+1
    % outputs "2"
\subsection{Subsection}
    Next subsection would be: \the\numexpr\thesubsection+1
    % prints literary "1.1+1" instead of "1.2"
\end{document}
```

Comment: `Next subsection would be: \thesection.\the\numexpr\value{subsection}+1\relax`

Comment: Obviously you wouldn't use this to refer to the next section or subsection, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the composite *display* as-is. You need to extract the *value* of the counter (using `\value`) which might be different from its *representation* (like `\alph` or `\roman`), perform your calculation (perhaps using `\numexpr`), and display the composition again (with `\the` or `\number`). Here are some ways of achieving this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
Next section would be: \the\numexpr\value{section}+1\relax \par
Next section would be: \ref{sec:another_section} \par
Next section would be: \stepcounter{section}\thesection\addtocounter{section}{-1}

\subsection{Subsection}
Next subsection would be: \thesection.\the\numexpr\value{subsection}+1\relax \par
Next subsection would be: \ref{sec:another_subsection} \par
Next subsection would be: \stepcounter{subsection}\thesubsection\addtocounter{subsection}{-1}

\subsection{Another subsection}\label{sec:another_subsection}

\section{Another section}\label{sec:another_section}

\end{document}
```

Using `\label`-`\ref` is far better, period.

Comment: Thanks Werner, for a good summary of methods. Indeed I was particularly interested in subsections and hoped to manipulate its representation, as in the headings where I need them the section and subsection counters are usually wrong. I solved it now by asking titlesec to save extramarks. Your answer was helpful.